# stop python program when ssh pipe is broken

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I'm writing a python script with an infinite while loop that I am running over ssh. I would like the script to terminate when someone kills ssh. For example:

The script (script.py):

```
while True:
    # do something
```

Will be run as:

```
ssh foo ./script.py
```

When I kill the ssh process, I would like the script on the other end to stop running.

I have tried looking for a closed stdout:

```
while not sys.stdout.closed:
    # do something
```

but this didn't work.

How do I achieve this?

**Edit**:

The remote machine is a Mac which opens the program in a csh:

```
502 29352 ??         0:00.01 tcsh -c python test.py
502 29354 ??         0:00.04 python test.py
```

I'm opening the ssh process from a python script like so:

```
p = Popen(['ssh','foo','./script.py'],stdout=PIPE)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    # etc
```

**EDIT**

Proposed Solutions:

1. Run the script with `while os.getppid() != 1`

This seems to work on Linux systems, but does **not** work when the remote machine is running OSX. The problem is that the command is launched in a csh (see above) and so the csh has its parent process id set to 1, but not the script.

1. Periodically log to `stderr`

This works, but the script is also run locally, and I don't want to print a heartbeat to `stderr`.

1. Run the script in a pseduo tty with `ssh -tt`.

This does work, but has some weird consequences. Consider the following:

remote_script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import time
import sys

while True:
    print time.time()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

local_script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time

p = Popen(['ssh','-tt','user@foo','remote_script'],stdout=PIPE)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline().strip()
    if line:
        print line
    else:
        break
    time.sleep(10)
```

First of all, the output is really weird, it seems to keep adding tabs or something:

```
[user@local ~]$ local_script 
1393608642.7
            1393608643.71
                         1393608644.71
                                      Connection to foo closed.
```

Second of all, the program does not quit the first time it receives a `SIGINT`, i.e. I have to hit Ctrl-C twice in order to kill the local_script.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: forcing tty via [`ssh -tt`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21731925/4279) does change the behaviour.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, it should force the behaviour. But have you tested it?, I did, without usefull results :/

Comment: @brunsgaard: yes. I've tested it. With `-tt` the Python script is killed on my machine.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, okay :) I just undeleted my post from the 12 th feb. My first answer was to this problem was to `-tt`, but when it did not work in my little test i deleted the answer.

Comment: @user545424, okay I saw you edit (update), if I were to work futher with this -  to find a better solution - I would look at other POSIX signals, (SIGHUP is in my opinion not 'great' for your usecase) take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP#POSIX_signals 
if you find a signal that 'works' it would be great, then you just have to change your handler to do perform sys.exit(). Also you can take the pid idea further, i will make an update to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest periodically logging to stderr.

This will cause an exception to occur when you no longer have a stderr to write to.

Comment: This does work, but the script is also used locally and I don't want to print a heartbeat to stderr.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I have a solution for you

When the ssh connection closes, the parent process id will change from the pid of the ssh-deamon (the fork that handles your connection) to 1.

Thus the following solves your problem.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

from time import sleep
import os

#os.getppid() returns parent pid
while (os.getppid() != 1):
    sleep(1)
    pass
```

Can you confirm this is working in your end too :)

**edit**

I saw you update.

This is not tested, but to get this idea working on OSX, you may be able to detect if the process of the `csh` changes. The code below only illustrates an idea and has not been tested. That said i think it would work, but it would not be the most elegant solution. If a cross platform solution using `signals` could be found, it would be preferred.

```
def do_stuff():
    sleep(1)

if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    tcsh_pid = os.getppid()
    sshfork_pid = psutil.Process(tcsh_pid).ppid
    while (sshfork_pid == psutil.Process(tcsh_pid).ppid)
       do_stuff()

elif sys.platform == 'linux':
    while (os.getppid() != 1):
        sleep(1)
else:
    raise Exception("platform not supported")

sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when running the script on OSX, because the parent process is `tcsh`.

Comment: @user545424, you can tell your parent shell to `exec ./yourscript` instead of just running `./yourscript` (so long as it doesn't need to do anything else); this will replace the shell with the Python script in the process tree, rather than putting it underneath.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
ssh -tt foo ./script.py
```

Comment: How would forcing a tty change this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

When the terminal connection is lost, the application is supposed to receive [SIGHUP signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP#SIGHUP), so all you have to do is to register a special handler using [signal module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal).

```
import signal
def MyHandler(self, signum, stackFrame):
    errorMessage = "I was stopped by %s" % signum
    raise Exception(errorMessage)

# somewhere in the beginning of the __main__:
# registering the handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, MyHandler)
```

Note that most likely you'll have to handle some other signals. You can do it in absolutely the same way.

Comment: if `SIGHUP` is sent ([sometimes it is not](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84737/1321)) then OP don't need to do anything because the default action for SIGHUP is to terminate the process.

Comment: Your approach to solving the problem is more correct than mine. That said, I think my solution works better in practice, since you cannot be sure that `SIGHUP` is send. (e.g. If the network connection is lost.)

Answer (score 0):

The running script is a child pid of the terminal session. If you close the SSH session properly it will terminate the process.  But, another method of going about this is to connect your while loop to another factor and disconnect it from your SSH session.

You can have your script controlled by cron to execute regularly. You can have the while loop have a counter.  You can have a sleep command in the loop to control execution.  Pretty much anything other than having it connected to your SSH session is valid.

To do this you could use exec  & to disconnect instances from your loop.