# Stop remote script ran over SSH

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi

My question might duplicate this post [stop python program when ssh pipe is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731267/stop-python-program-when-ssh-pipe-is-broken) but the only answers i could test(ssh -tt, ssh -t and ssh -T) didn't work for my case.

Here is the command i use in git bash to run a local python script over ssh on the raspberry pi:

`ssh python3 < 01_LED.py`

Here is the script content:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

def main():
    red = LED(24)

    while True:
        red.on()
        print('LED is on')
        sleep(1)
        red.off()
        print('LED is off')
        sleep(1)
main()
```

What i would like to get is this:

1. Get all the script output in the local git bash terminal;
2. Press CTRL-C to end the script locally and on the pi.

What is the simplest approach i could use to achieve this?

I'm fairly new to this topic so any detailed answers or documentation links would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this solution worked for me: `cat 01_LED.py | ssh python3 -u`